# How to redirect urls to the symfony project/environment?

Tags: symfony, controller

I'm working my way through Symfony tutorials and the urls on localhost don't match what they should be according to the tutorials so I'm guessing I must have missed something? For example, one tutorial deals with requests to:

`localhost/hello/fabien`

However, I get a `Not Found. The requested URL /hello/Fabien was not found on this server`. I only get the correct result if I use:

`localhost/app_dev.php/hello/fabien`

Comment: Which version are you using? The `/hello/{name}` path was in the `AcmeDemoBundle` which is no longer (since 2.5) part of the standard edition. For 2.5+ the only available path would be `/app/example` from the `AppBundle`.

Comment: Check the url: http://localhost/app.php/hello/fabien If this work then  check that you have enable the Apache Module for the RewriteRule.

Comment: Thanks both. @Qoop, I'm using v2.6.1. I installed Symfony yesterday morning and I have a `/src/Acme/DemoBundle` directory still? @Matteo, I've triepd the production path you gave and I just get a blank page returned

Comment: of course, check the AppKernel files for check prod configuration. This bundle is not enable in prod by default

Comment: Are your `app/cache` and `app/logs` project directories are writable for your web-server user/group?

Comment: @Matteo I tried adding AcheDemoBundle to the prod section of AppKernel but no luck there - I wonder whether my problem may be the Apache Module you mentioned originally? (despite app.php gave a blank page). I understand that all requests should go to  app.php/app_dev.php but I don't know what I need to change to make it 'silent' and not appear in the URL path every time

Comment: after enable the acmedemobundle in prod env have you clear the sf cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## mod_rewrite

Create a simple php file with the following content:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And search for mod_rewrite on the php info page, if it doesn't bring anything up, issue the following commands on the server:

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

## Dev Bundles

Please check your `app/AppKernel.php`and make sure that the bundle where the route is in is loaded in **prod** environment.

If you see this:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    $bundles[] = new Bundle\YourBundle\BundleYourBundle();
}
```

That means BundleYourBundle will only be loaded in **dev** and **test** environment.

Also make sure the routes are being imported in `routing.yml`not `routing_dev.yml`.

## prod log

Check the bottom of `app/logs/prod.log` for an error.

## .htaccess / Routing / prod cache

Look at the **.htaccess** file, it redirects request like `/hello/fabien` to `/app.php/hello/fabien`. That should fire up the **prod** environment. The **prod** environment however has most files (e.g. yml and twig files) cached and serves them from cache for performance reasons.

This means you need to clear the **prod** cache after adding/changing routes.

Check `app/console router:debug --env=prod`

## Clearing the cache

You either do `app/console cache:clear --env=prod`on the console or delete the folder app/cache/prod.

Comment: thanks - I cleared the prod cache but still when I go to `/app.php/hello/fabien` though I just get a blank page returned (whereas `/app_dev.php/hello/fabien` works)

Comment: I added the sections **dev bundles** and **prod log**, hope it helps.

Comment: Also check my updates to the section **.htaccess / Routing / prod cache**

Comment: Thanks @MarcelBurkhard - My `prod.log` has 6 errors but they are just for references to images I haven't copied over yet. I think my problem may be in .htaccess. As you described it, when I enter `localhost/hello/Fabien` it isn't being redirected to `localhost/app_dev.php/hello/Fabien` as it should be. I will update my question to include my .htaccess. Thanks again

Comment: You shouldn't make any changes to the .htaccess!

Have you checked ```app/console router:debug --env=prod``` ? Is your route in there?

Comment: ...closed! Thanks for the warning - I haven't made any changes! When I try the `app/console router:debug --env=prod` I just the error message: `[UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  The stream or file "/home/Zac/Project/test/app/logs/dev.log" could n  
  ot be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: Fire ```chgrp www-data -R /home/Zac/Project/test``` and then try again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68343/discussion-between-bendy-and-marcel-burkhard).